# What is Context free & Context dependent resources in ASP.Net core web application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I was going through some TPL best practices links

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx
- http://www.msevestre.ca/when-to-use-configureawait-in-asynchronous-programming/

Based on this, this is how I build my asynchronous call ladder.

```
 //UI call the below API
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
     //#1 .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            var flag = await _appRepository.AddCustomer(customer).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (flag)
            {
                //OK
            }
            else
            {
                //Internal Server Error
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    //Service Layer or DAL method
    public async Task<bool> AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
    //#2 .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Now I am not clear with the two terminology

- Context-free
- Context-dependant

As per the above link, I should be using `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` for Context-dependant resources

How do I identify between these two & if referred the pasted code-snippet where does `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` rightly fits?

Comment: Asp.net core does not have a synchronization context so `ConfigureAwait` isn't doing anything for you. You must still `await` async calls though.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Do you mean to say `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);`  is NOT making difference if it's  `ASP.Net core`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for infomation!! but still can you please put some light on ContextFree & ContextDepedant thing?

Comment: Regarding core, [see this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html). Context dependent means you must resume continuations on the context you captured upon awaiting if you are using thread-specific state. Previous to Core an example would be HttpContext.Current.

Comment: @Crowcoder cool. Many Thanks!!